# How to recover control deleted from ToolBox In Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, toolbox

I've deleted a tool from ToolBox by accident. How I can get it back if possible?

Comment: Step 1: Accept some answers.  (You may have noticed this pattern in your previous questions.)

Comment: @skaffman: Perhaps my pessimism is half-full today.

Comment: How to accept i have made the arrow up which increase the value at there. is there any other way please tell me how to accept?

Comment: @ David,skaffman:  I'm Not getting about what u are talking?

Comment: @jagdeep: You accept answers using the tick symbol next to them. See the FAQ.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard way is to select the tab in the toolbox and select "Choose Items", this opens a window that allows you a list of controls to add, or you can browse to find the control in it's assembly if it is not there.

You can also restore the toolbox to the original configuration with a Right Click on the Toolbox and select "Reset Toolbox" (**WARNING**: This will give you the **VS defaults**.  If you loaded any control libraries, **you will lose them** and have to reload them with their installer or "Choose Items").

Comment: @ skeeve :It does not showing the option on right click. The options shown are: hide, auto-hide,floating,dockable

Comment: @jagdeep And on a Tool icon not the Toolbox title?

Answer (score 5):

Just right click any tool and select reset toolbox....you will get the deleted tool.

Comment: Will this not reset it to default removing any non-default tools that they had shown?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This is based on memory.
Right click on Toolbox, you should get properties/configure or Add Control option. Select that option and a dialog box will appear listing all types (.net, COM) of control. Select the control that has gone missing and it should be back to your toolbox.

Comment: @ Pradeep: I'm not getting the description u have told after right clicking on the tool box

Answer (score 0):

If reset toolbox does not help please try the following:
- right click on the blank toolbox area and select the option "Add/remove Items";
- click on the browse button;
- if 'Windows Forms' controls are missing navigate to:
    C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vx.xxxx\System.Windows.Forms.dll
- if 'Web' controls are missing navigate to:
    C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vx.xxxx\System.Web.dll
- and press OK.

The controls should then appear on the relevant tabs.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studios or other visual stuff, to reset the toolbox and other tools click windows then go to reset windows layout.

Comment: All caps probably isn't strictly necessary.